# Can't find smoke and color mapping options for Fluid Simulation Blender 2.9

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, baking

I am trying to make an explosion with Blender Mantaflow, but I do not see the following in the Properties view in the Physics Properties:

- Color Mapping
- Smoke

[image]

I am using Blender 2.91.
Can you help me solve the problem?

Comment: I think it's because you are using a domain object. To access smoke properties, make it a flow object, and pick Flow Type: Smoke.

Comment: No, he means some older domain settings, the _Color Mapping_ is now _Grid Display_. But I'm not sure about the _Smoke Settings_... as far as I remember you could choose the _Type_, but the domain is already set to smoke.

Comment: EDIT (too late for editing actually): Under _Smoke_ there were settings for _Buoyancy Density_, _Buoyancy Heat_ and _Vorticity_. But they are right there in his screenshot, they are simply not labeled "Smoke" anymore, but "Gas".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this was renamed to "Grid Display" after blender 2.90. See [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.91/physics/fluid/type/domain/gas/viewport_display.html) for some usage info. Compare the docs between versions 2.83 and 2.91.

The *Smoke* settings *Buoyancy Density*, *Buoyancy Heat* and *Vorticity* are now labeled *Gas*, you can see them in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The smoke label is changed to gas, while the color mapping is changed to Grid display.